# how to eliminate duplicate rows in column A keeping the maximum value in B in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with data from an excel file like this.

```
A                  B
2001-05-01 12:30   10
2001-05-01 12:30   20
2001-05-05 11:50   30
2001-05-05 11:50   40
2002-03-22 14:12   10
```

I'm using this line of code to eliminate the duplicates keeping the maximum

`df_clean=df_raw.sort_values('A', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('B').sort_index()`

but I'm obtaining this error

`Index(['B'], dtype='object')`

I don't know which could be the problem since I'm doing it after the upload of the file.

Comment: This works fine for me, you must have a typo or the wrong dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can assume that your index is just a `RangeIndex` then I think what you are looking for is:

```
df_clean=df_raw.sort_values('A', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('B', ignore_index=True)
```

and not `sort_index()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your second column name contains some spaces before "B" something like:

`"     B"`

Just try :

```py
df_raw.columns = ["A","B"]
```

before your statement